# Can't create a loop to print items in a customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to parse the content of a webpage using requests. The content appears to be within a table but in reality there is no tr or td tag. However, as the content is dynamic, I thought to make use of selenium to grab them. The script that I've written so far can grab them in a single line. What I wish to do now is print every 5 items in a row and so on like the way they are visible in that site.

[website address](https://www.usdebtclock.org/world-debt-clock.html)

I've written so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://www.usdebtclock.org/world-debt-clock.html'

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    driver.get(link)
    for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='layer'] > span"))):
        print(elem.text)
```

Output I'm getting are like:

```
330,151,536
$26,755,252,293,256
103.70%
$19,568,761,011,755
128.27%
1,438,097,306
$7,331,488,897,052
50.34%
$14,562,936,025,896
15.94%
126,619,535
$12,174,468,045,729
268.35%
$4,536,842,867,333
```

Output I wish to get:

```
330,151,536 $26,755,252,293,256 103.70% $19,568,761,011,755 128.27%
1,438,097,306 $7,331,488,897,052 50.34% $14,562,936,025,896 15.94%
126,619,535 $12,174,468,045,729 268.35% $4,536,842,867,333 91.86%
83,793,324 $2,936,570,308,213 78.11% $3,759,189,613,048 166.88%
```

***How can I achieve the expected output?***

Comment: It's Selenium not Request.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I mentioned it as well in the post @Parsa Fat'hollahi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this problem by creating an array to hold all your results, and have each result represented as an array itself.

I haven't tested this code, but the idea is that you add elements into their own "row" until you come across one with a "%". Then, you would set found_percent to True. Once you find another, which means that's the last element in the row, you add the current row (which is complete) to your results, and erase `current_row` so you can put the next row in it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = 'https://www.usdebtclock.org/world-debt-clock.html'
results = []

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    driver.get(link)

    current_row = []
    found_first_percent = False

    for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='layer'] > span"))):
        current_row.append(elem)
        if "%" in elem:
            if found_first_percent:
                results.append(current_row)
                current_row = []
                found_first_percent = False
            else:
                found_first_percent = True

for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Comment: I slightly modified your suggestion and ended up doing like ***[this](https://pastebin.com/9AhcwwcX)*** eventually. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a perfect match for list chunking.

Chop up the list of elements you get into a list of 5-element lists. Then loop over that, joining the sub-lists and printing them.

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


link = 'https://www.usdebtclock.org/world-debt-clock.html'


def chunks(_list, chunk_size):
    for i in range(0, len(_list), chunk_size):
        yield _list[i:i + chunk_size]


with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get(link)
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id^='layer'] > span")))
    for chunk in chunks(elements, 5):
        print(' '.join(e.text for e in chunk))
```

Output:

```
330,151,637 $26,755,352,639,988 103.70% $19,568,816,364,550 128.26%
1,438,097,743 $7,331,515,883,064 50.34% $14,562,956,376,740 15.94%
126,619,510 $12,174,512,856,639 268.35% $4,536,849,207,058 91.86%
83,793,352 $2,936,581,116,897 78.11% $3,759,192,266,049 166.88%
and so on...
```

Comment: Your solution is doing the job perfectly. I wish I could accept both the answers. Thanks.